# Navigation fade in after scroll down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, mootools, fadein

I would like to get a navigation exactly like this website : http://www.interviewmagazine.com/

A navigation bar appears after scrolling down about 700 pixels or so..  its a fixed nav with fade in effect and has a fade out effect when you scroll back to top.

I tried to see how they did their code but i couldnt figure it out.

sounds like mootools tho?

If someone can help that would be awesome.  thanks!

Comment: Nobody is going to just hand you code. Maybe try thinking about how you would tackle the problem, and come back if you're stuck

Comment: Well i honestly dont know where to start. Well i mean im sure i should start by making the fixed nav at the top but I dont know what i would do next.

Comment: To start try `ctrl-u` on their site and have a look at their code.  I think it is jQuery not mootools that handles this.  Have a look at their home.js http://www.interviewmagazine.com/script/home.js

Answer (score 2):

You can create such a menu using jQuery and CSS, swapping classes as needed when:

```
var posit = window.scrollTop();
if (posit == [your designated fadein location]) {
    //do something;
}

CSS: position : fixed, opacity : 0, height : 0; overflow : hidden
```

swap class to change height to fixed amount

```
animate({opacity : 1.0}, 'fast', function() {
    //callback;
});
```

You'll have to set a listener for when user scrolls, but this should get you started. All you need is jQuery and a browser, a logical approach to cut the project up into manageable parts, and time.

EDIT: Here's your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/lazerblade01/fNn7K/26/

Comment: Thanks, i have no idea how to finish the code..im horrible with javascript.

Comment: Sorry, if I had the time and patience I'd give it a shot but it's not happening tonight. If you can't figure it out, let me know and maybe I can get you started with a well-documented template where you can just plug in what you need to.

Comment: If you can I'd REALLY appreciate it !  I really cant seem to get it.  I can get the fixed nav but cant get the javascript to work.

Comment: Hey did you by any chance get to make that template for me?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone searching through stackoverflow here is my try:

```
$(function(){
    // Check the initial Poistion of  Sticky Header
    var stickyHeaderTop = $('#stickyheader').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
            if( $(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderTop ) {
                    $('#stickyheader').css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
                    $('#stickyheader').css('opacity', '1');
            } else {
                    $('#stickyheader').css({position: 'static', top: '600px'});
                    $('#stickyheader').css('opacity', '0');
            }
    }); 
 });
```

Here is a **Fiddle DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/uFq2k/297/

It is a little modified version of this code: [how can I stick the div after scrolling down a little](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496240/how-can-i-stick-the-div-after-scrolling-down-a-little)

Comment: aaah thx - very cool. and when i want it to start after an amount of pixels i simply do:
"var stickyHeaderTop = $('nav').offset().top + 200;"

Answer (score 1):

David Walsh has a thing he calls ScrollSpy - much like twitter's scroll spy - only it does a different thing.

the twitter one can react to a particular element of interest coming into view.

walsh's plugin can react and give you events when a user scrolls to a particular threshold and back.

http://davidwalsh.name/mootools-scrollspy

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html). Check out their second toolbar.

Comment: Not sure why, but that page is _really_ jittery in Safari on my Mac.  Weird.

Comment: Really, that's lame. Have you used Atlassian's Jira? It has a pretty slick fade transition on their ticket system while scrolling.

Comment: Haven't used it in Safari, though I never had problems with it in Firefox.  The link from the question is pretty smooth on any browser I use right now.  (And it's a pretty cool effect, I may have to use it at some point.)

Comment: Yea, I hadn't actually looked at the link. Just read his description. After checking it out. It is nifty, not really a slide in effect though, just a fade in after a certain distance. Seems useful, but it might only work on tall artistic sites like that. Who knows.