# How to fix the header to top After Scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

Logo:

[image: Logo**strong text**]

My Header has a Logo. How to Fix it at top after scrolling? 
Here is My code please Help!! stucked

Comment: There is no code. This is not how you ask questions on Stack Overflow. Fixing something after scrolling sounds like “sticky positioning”.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if we could see your code, but I have a feeling that this is a duplicate anyways.

Try here: [how can I stick the div after scrolling down a little](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496240/how-can-i-stick-the-div-after-scrolling-down-a-little)

OR Try here: [Make a nav bar stick to the top when scrolling with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452235/make-a-nav-bar-stick-to-the-top-when-scrolling-with-css)

Also, https://css-tricks.com/ could help you out with this.